# Login Authentication from a database on Java SE

Tags: java

Please I am creating a login page on netbeans GUI creator.I have a table on my database that stores username.
How do i make the login botton check for the username on my database and if the username exists,the next page should open?
Thank You

Comment: I wish there was a button to see the code you have tried ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but maybe you could get this done by googling it, anyway...

- use PreparedStatement and the wildcard "?" for the search of "username" in your database, is easy to get information about this on internet.
- set an ActionListener to your button, here in this ActionListener is where you will put the code for check if the username exist on your database or not (this is another thing you could easy found "how to" on internet.
- if the username exist show the new "page" "frame" or whatever you will show to the user.
- after all this set the ActionListener to the button login button (althought this will be in the "how to" of ActionListener.

as a plus, remember that database code should be separate from View code, what i mean with this is that your username check should be something like DatabaseManager.userExist(String username) and it returns a boolean, don't manage all your connection, your query and the result of that query in your ActionListener code, that's just wrong, just saying, as a good practice.

hope to be helpful, regard.